# Combining multiple functions having ' and " with a foreach

Tags: php, foreach

I am trying to combine

```
genesis_widget_area( 'front-page-1', array(
    'before' => '<div class="front-page-1"><div class="widget-area fadeup-effect"><div class="wrap">',
    'after'  => '</div></div></div>',
) );

genesis_widget_area( 'front-page-2', array(
    'before' => '<div class="front-page-2"><div class="widget-area fadeup-effect"><div class="wrap">',
    'after'  => '</div></div></div>',
) );

genesis_widget_area( 'front-page-3', array(
    'before' => '<div class="front-page-3"><div class="widget-area fadeup-effect"><div class="wrap">',
    'after'  => '</div></div></div>',
) );

genesis_widget_area( 'front-page-4', array(
    'before' => '<div class="front-page-4"><div class="widget-area fadeup-effect"><div class="wrap">',
    'after'  => '</div></div></div>',
) );

genesis_widget_area( 'front-page-5', array(
    'before' => '<div class="front-page-5"><div class="widget-area fadeup-effect"><div class="wrap">',
    'after'  => '</div></div></div>',
) );
```

into a single foreach loop.

Here's my non-working attempt:

```
$section_numbers = array( '1', '2', '3', '4', '5' );

foreach ( $section_numbers as $section_number ) {
    genesis_widget_area( "'front-page-".$section_number."'", array(
        'before' => '<div class="front-page-"'.$section_number.'"><div class="widget-area fadeup-effect"><div class="wrap">',
        'after'  => '</div></div></div>',
    ) );
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: your quotes are all over the place.

Comment: You don't need quotes inside quotes.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a quote issue.

try with

```
$section_numbers = array( 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 );
```

or with a for loop where you replace $section_number by the iteration key :

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++) {
    /* your code */
}
```

good luck

Answer (score 0):

This did the trick:

```
$section_numbers = array( '1', '2', '3', '4', '5' );

foreach ( $section_numbers as $section_number ) {
    genesis_widget_area( "front-page-{$section_number}", array(
        'before' => '<div class="front-page-'.$section_number.'"><div class="widget-area fadeup-effect"><div class="wrap">',
        'after'  => '</div></div></div>',
    ) );
}
```

@ArtisticPhoenix: Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Try this.

```
$section_numbers = array( '1', '2', '3', '4', '5' );

foreach ( $section_numbers as $section_number ) {
    genesis_widget_area( "front-page-{$section_number}", array(
        'before' => '<div class="front-page-"'.$section_number.'"><div class="widget-area fadeup-effect"><div class="wrap">',
        'after'  => '</div></div></div>',
    ) );
}
```

Specifically

```
 "front-page-{$section_number}"
```

Instead of ( this one with extra quotes )

```
"'front-page-".$section_number."'"
```

You could also do it this way

```
"front-page-".$section_number
```

OR

```
'front-page-'.$section_number
```

Essentially what your doing in looking for this widget area

```
'front-page-1'
```

instead of just

```
 front-page-1
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

I tried your code block but it is resulting in slightly incorrect markup: http://d.pr/i/LsJk

I'll try your other suggestions..

Comment: Sure it was a simple mistake.  Feel free to accept the answer if it solves the problem.